# How can I add/remove an html element depending on a checkbox being selected with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like an html  to appear only when a checkbox in a form is selected. How can I do this with only javascript?

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="exampleCheckbox">
  </form>
  <div id="toggleElement"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
What I have tried, but it does not disappear after being unselected:

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="exampleCheckbox" onclick="showDiv()">
  </form>
  <div id="toggleElement"></div>
  <script>
  function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById("toggleElement").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anything you've tried already?

Comment: @Ignaus yes, sorry I'll edit it to add that portion

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @Zuzlx I can't use jQuery because I'm limited by the characters I can send, so using an external library would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using eventlistener:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener('change',function() {
        var hidden = document.getElementById("html");
        if (this.checked) {
            hidden.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            hidden.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7wdkd7a/3/

Comment: granted this has less support (read: modern browsers, with no funky css caveats), you can `document.getElementById("html").hidden = this.checked` .hidden will display:none; it but has the lowest specificity so anything else will override it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onchange` event to the checkbox, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="exampleCheckbox" onchange="myFunction()">
```

So `myFunction` will be called when the checkbox changes.

Then in your script:

```
function myFunction()
{
    // First check the state of the checkbox:
    if (document.getELementById("exampleCheckbox").checked) {
        // if it is checked, show the element:
        document.getElementById("toggleElement").style.visibility = "visible"; // make the div visible
    } else {
        // the checkbox is unchecked
        document.getElementById("toggleElement").style.visibility = "hidden"; // make the div invisible
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this require having a css file?

Comment: No, because you are setting the CSS directly inside javascript code.

Comment: You are mixing jquery and vanilla. There is no .css

Comment: @rlemon Yes I saw, fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: I must have commented while you were editing. Or you are insane fast.